# moving elements in a 3x3 array based on user input(choice of up, down, left, or right)

Tags: c++, arrays

so basically i need help on taking an existing array and moving a specific number in that array that is 3X3 and move it up down, etc.., after its moved the values around it need to move accordingly.
example
123
321
123

i want to move spot (3, 2) to the left
123
213
123

also the same for up and down elements
the program will also keep up with the spot you in and change them accordingly

my program will need to keep track of the coordinates too, that i have yet to figure out how to implement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void printarray(int num[3][3])
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++)
        {
            cout << num[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void swapValues(int (&array)[3][3], int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2)
{
    int temp = array[i1][j1];
    array[i1][j1] = array[i2][j2];
    array[i2][j2] = temp;
}

void moveleft(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    if (i>0 && i<3 && j>=0 && j<3)
    {
        swapValues(array, i, j, i-1, j);
        swapValues(array, i, j, i+1, j);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "wrong move!" << endl;
    }
    //swapValues(array, i, j, i, j-1);
    //swapValues(array, i, j, i, j+1);
}

void movedown(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    swapValues(array, i+1, j, i, j);
    swapValues(array, i-1, j, i, j);
}

void moveright(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    swapValues(array, i, j+1, i, j);
    swapValues(array, i, j-1, i, j);
}

void moveup(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    //here you MUST check the indexes to make sure you CAN move left
    //int lim = (3*3)-1;
    //for(int x = lim; x >= 1; x--)
    //{

    swapValues(array, i, j, i-1, j);
    swapValues(array, i, j, i+1, j);
    int coord1d = j * 3 + i;
}

class Puzzle
{
public:
    Puzzle();
    void swapValues(int num[3][3], int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2);
    //void moveleft(int[3][3], int start1, int start2);
    void moveup(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j);
    void moveright(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j);
    void moveleft(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j);
    void movedown(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j);
    void printarray(int[3][3]);
};

int main()
{
    int state1[3][3] = {{2, 8, 3}, {1, 6, 4}, {7, 0, 5}};
    int state2[3][3] = {{2, 8, 1}, {4, 6, 3}, {0, 7, 5}};
    int gstate[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {8, 0, 4}, {7, 6, 5}};
    cout << "this is state 1" << endl;
    printarray(state1);
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "now this is state 2" << endl;
    printarray(state2);
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "now this is the goal state" << endl;;
    printarray(gstate);
    int start1, start2;
    cout << endl << endl << "please enter your starting point in the states listed above on the x axis(left to right)" << endl;
    cin >> start1;
    cout << "now enter the point on the y axis(up or down)" << endl;
    cin >> start2;
    //moveleft(state1, start1, start2);
    cout << "this is moving coordinate (1, 1) upwards" << endl;
    moveup(state1, start1, start2);
    printarray(state1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "this is moving coordinate (1, 1) to the left" << endl;
    moveleft(state1, start1, start2);
    printarray(state1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "this is moving coordinate (1, 1) downwards" << endl;
    movedown(state1, start1, start2);
    printarray(state1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "this is moving coordinate (1, 1) to the right" << endl;
    moveright(state1, start1, start2);
    printarray(state1);
    cout << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

please give me code examples, explanations are good, but never clear enough for me.
not asking you to give answer, just help me see the right answer

- so i have updated my code and it sorta kinda works, the only problem is that when i use any other coordinates besides the ones (1, 1) then i get memory addresses instead of array numbers. Any explanation on this would be greatly appreciated, i have no idea how to fix a problem like this because im not really sure how the problem is even there?

also that code is completely compilable and ready to go, so run to see what i mean if i didnt explain well enough.

Comment: Can you brief about what the code shown does for you and what it doesn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution

Use this function to swap the values at given indexes

```
void swapValues(int (&array)[3][3], int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2)
{
    int temp = array[i1][j1];
    array[i1][j1] = array[i2][j2];
    array[i2][j2] = temp;
}
```

Then, for example, your `moveLeft` will be like this

```
void moveLeft(int (&array)[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    if (i>0 && i<3 && j>=0 && j<3)
    {
        swapValues(array, i, j, i-1, j);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "wrong move!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that I pass the array as reference, otherwise your modifications won't be visible in your `main` function

Comment: Please clarify what you mean for "my program will need to keep track of the coordinates too"

Comment: i got an error in the code you used, where the array[][] is, im getting the *error: an array may not have elements of this type* also i meant by keeping track of the coordinates like, the position you would be in the 2d array, example( 2 to the right and 2 down would be 6 so i would have a small coordinates back to let the user known his or her coordinates.

Comment: ok I corrected my answer, still don't get why 2 to the right and 2 down is 6

Comment: also, what exactly do you mean when you say check the indexes to make sure you can move left? oh, also i meant 1 to the right and 1 down, that would be 6 in the first array, sorry about that.

Comment: now I may have got it: if you want to translate your 2d coordinate in a 1d coordinate of a plain array is `coord1d = j * 3 + i`

Comment: what if you want to, for example, move to left in 0,0? you can't. in this case you have to check that `i>0` (and also, depending on the program, if `i<3` and `0<=j<3`)

Comment: okay i believe i got that one but still what do you mean when you say check indexes? and how would i go about doing it?

Comment: okay i just compiled the code and somehow it managed to move the spot i want up lol, so since that was still technically a part of what i was trying to do then awesome. but now i need to know how to move the values actually to the right and left, so basically up or down. any suggestions, also thank you so much for the help, this has been extremely useful.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, i edited my answer and gave my new problem in detail, my code is almost there but still some odd errors here and there.